# How to rotate a object trail in vpython?

Tags: python-3.x, vpython

I want to write a program to simulate 5-axis cnc gcode with vpython and I need to rotate trail of the object that's moving. Any idea how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly what you need, but if instead of using "make_trail=True" simply create a curve object to which you append points. A curve object named "c" can be rotated using the usual way to rotate an object: c.rotate(.....).